# How do I update rows using while loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

I'm trying to update the SQL rows where the update query is located in the while loop.

```
DECLARE @Sayac INT
SET @Sayac= (select count(ABBREVIATION) from [MSTR_MD].[dbo].[v_OpcoGeneral_UserList])
WHILE (@Sayac>0)
BEGIN
    PRINT @Sayac;
    (select ABBREVIATION FROM  [MSTR_MD].[dbo].[v_OpcoGeneral_UserList] WHERE [MSTR_MD].[dbo].[v_OpcoGeneral_UserList].ID = @Sayac)
 UPDATE [dwh].[dbo].[opco_securty]
 SET opco_general = REPLACE(opco_general, (select ABBREVIATION FROM  [MSTR_MD].[dbo].[v_OpcoGeneral_UserList] WHERE [MSTR_MD].[dbo].[v_OpcoGeneral_UserList].ID = @Sayac), '')
    SET @Sayac = @Sayac - 1

END
```

But in this query, it doesn't work as expected. I guess the while loop is not being compiled like in programming languages. Could you please recommend a solution? Thanks!

Basically for instance, if "Ugurcan.Kaya" is received from the view, remove "Ugurcan.Kaya" from the opco_general (text) column on  the opco_securty table.

[image]

Comment: The intended logic looks strange.  Why would you want to compare a count with the id column?  That feels like a mistake.  Can you clarify the requirement in the question?

Comment: I'm receiving the user id's from [MSTR_MD].[dbo].[v_OpcoGeneral_UserList] and want to replace the text where the retrieved user id exists on the opco_security table.

Comment: Basically for instance, if "Ugurcan.Kaya" is received from the view, remove "Ugurcan.Kaya" from the opco_general column on  the opco_securty table.

Comment: Please update the question with a minimal reproducible test case.  But you're using a COUNT to compare against the user id.  That seems like a mistake.

Comment: ABBREVIATION is going to be equal to 'Ugurcan.Kaya', I use that line to set the counter of the loop (how many rows coming from the view)

Comment: `WHERE [MSTR_MD].[dbo].[v_OpcoGeneral_UserList].ID = @Sayac`  is just wrong, most likely.  Please update the question to contain a test case, `CREATE TABLE` statements, `INSERT` statements and the resultant changes you would like to make to  the `opco_securty` table.  You don't need the exact tables, just the columns required to show the goal and it needs to be valid/executable.

Comment: To define my requirement I uploaded the image. Much appreciated.

Comment: The update statement looks incorrect just in general. Are you really meaning to update EVERY record in the Opco_Securty (is that spelled correctly) table? You have no `where` condition on the `update` which could cause problems for you. Agree with others that some example data and example output would be very helpful.

Comment: @DonkeyKongII No where clause needed :) It repeats for every row as same. (Used for row level security in a project)

Comment: *"How do I update rows using while loop?"* The better question is why would you want to `UPDATE` rows using a `WHILE` loop? SQL is a set based language, and thus excels at set based solutions. Unsurprisingly, as a result, it does poorly at iterative tasks, like a loop.

Comment: I couldn't figure out any other way to remove the particular text in a row.

Comment: You would better off showing us what you are actually trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do what you're trying to do without the loop using a recursive CTE. I borrowed the idea from this post [Multiple replacements in string in single Update Statement in SQL server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346791/multiple-replacements-in-string-in-single-update-statement-in-sql-server-2005)

I arranged it so that I believe it will work with your use case. The first CTE uses the recursion to continue to apply replacements until no more matches exist.

The second CTE is used to identify the row_number for each recursive replace that occurred. The row_number that we are interested in is the highest row_number per string from the `securty` table as that will have all the required replacements in it.

Lastly we run an update statement that updates each record in the `securty` table with the appropriate replaced string.

Here's the code that I wrote to make this work, with example data and tables:

```
CREATE TABLE UserList(
  id int,
  abbr varchar(25)
);

CREATE TABLE securty(
  id int,
  genrl varchar(250)
);

INSERT INTO UserList(id, abbr)
VALUES(1, 'Ugurcan.Kaya');

INSERT INTO UserList(id, abbr)
VALUES(2, 'User5');

INSERT INTO UserList(id, abbr)
VALUES(3, 'User6');

INSERT INTO securty(id, genrl)
VALUES(1, 'User1-User2-Ugurcan.Kaya-Lorum-User5-User16-User17');

INSERT INTO securty(id, genrl)
VALUES(2, 'User5-Ugurcan.Kaya-Lorum-User5-User16-User17');

;With Replacements as (
    SELECT
        s.id, s.genrl, 0 AS repcount
    FROM
        securty AS s
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      rs.id, CAST(REPLACE(genrl, ul.abbr, '') AS VARCHAR(250)),rs.repcount+1
    FROM
        Replacements rs
    JOIN
        UserList ul ON CHARINDEX(ul.abbr,rs.genrl) > 0
),
Final_Replacements AS (
  SELECT
    rs.id, rs.genrl, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rs.id ORDER BY rs.repcount DESC) AS rn
  FROM
    replacements AS rs
)
UPDATE s
SET s.genrl = fs.genrl
FROM securty AS s
JOIN Final_Replacements AS fs
  ON fs.id = s.id AND fs.rn = 1
```

I also created a sqlfiddle for you to try it out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/904e0/1/0

Answer (score 2):

[The fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7d7af2ae24ba903b9a2b8ec6f35978a0)

Maybe this will help understand one approach to applying a set of replacement patterns to your target table in an `UPDATE` statement.

Just to clarify, `REPLACE` will replace all the matched occurrences in a string, as seen in the last example string... `'6this is XYZ another XYZ test'` is updated to `'6this is  another  test'`.

From the t-sql documentation:

> REPLACE (Transact-SQL)
>
> Replaces all occurrences of a specified string value with another string value.

The SQL:

```sql
UPDATE test
   SET test.data = REPLACE(data, pattern, '')
  FROM test
  JOIN abbrev
    ON test.data LIKE CONCAT('%', pattern, '%')
;
```

The setup:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test ( id int, data varchar(40) );

INSERT INTO test VALUES
    ( 1, '1this is a NameToRemove test' )
  , ( 2, '2this is a NameToNotRemove test' )
  , ( 3, '3this is another NameXToRemove test' )
  , ( 4, '4this is another NameXToRemove test' )
  , ( 5, '5this is another NameXToRemove test' )
  , ( 6, '6this is XYZ another XYZ test' )
;

CREATE TABLE abbrev ( id int, pattern varchar(20) );
INSERT INTO abbrev VALUES
    ( 1, 'NameToRemove' )
  , ( 2, 'NameXToRemove' )
  , ( 3, 'NameZToRemove' )
  , ( 4, 'XYZ' )
;
```

The data:

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1this is a NameToRemove test |
| 2 | 2this is a NameToNotRemove test |
| 3 | 3this is another NameXToRemove test |
| 4 | 4this is another NameXToRemove test |
| 5 | 5this is another NameXToRemove test |
| 6 | 6this is XYZ another XYZ test |

The result:

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1this is a test |
| 2 | 2this is a NameToNotRemove test |
| 3 | 3this is another test |
| 4 | 4this is another test |
| 5 | 5this is another test |
| 6 | 6this is another test |

Comment: This does assume a row can't have more than one abbreviation.

Comment: That's right.  It's just an example.  Other slightly different methods can be used if there are additional requirements not seen in the problem data.

Comment: @Larnu Actually, REPLACE does handle replacing all the matched patterns in the string, at least in some cases.  I'll update the test case.

Comment: But it will have problems with multiple different replacements.

Comment: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=66713a98e10cb541a11ae91004eef991) showing what happens with multiple matches.

Comment: @Larnu Agreed.  Without regular expression support for this replace operation, we're probably left with the recursive approach.